# Adding attributes to socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a simple Node.js and socket.io project. I want to save the client's username as an attribute so I could delete their name if they quit.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    // grabs all the connected users
    io.emit('update users', Array.from(connectedUsers));
  
    socket.on('join game', (username) => {
        console.log(username + ' joined the game');
        connectedUsers.add(username);
        // applies their name to the socket
        socket.data.username = username;
    
        io.emit('update users', Array.from(connectedUsers));
    
        socket.emit('redirect', '/game');
    });

    socket.on('leave game', () => {
        console.log(socket.data.username + ' left the game');
        connectedUsers.delete(socket.data.username);
    
        io.emit('update users', Array.from(connectedUsers));
    });

});
```

This is my current server logic, I try adding a username attribute on the join game topic, and try to call it in the leave game topic. The issue is it always returns undefined.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I believe the issue is I am changing pages thus creating a new socket connection

Comment: custom socket properties are not permanent.  They only exist for the lifetime of that particular socket object.  If the user navigates to a new page, that drops the current socket.io connection and creates a new one that will not have your custom properties.  This is just the way it is.  Persistent data is more typically stored in a server-side user session object not on the socket object.